# Uniformly equivalent metrics

Tags: real-analysis

Could I ask for help in the following homework question?

> Given any metric space $(M, d)$, show that the metric $\rho = d /(1 + d)$ is always **uniformly equivalent** to $d$ but that there are cases in which the inequality $d < C \rho$ may fail to hold.

Does equivalent imply uniformly equivalent?

Comment: Have you made any effort on the problem yet? On this site, you will receive better feedback if you explain where you need help.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to show that $\rho$ is a metric. Define
   $$\varphi(t) = \frac{t}{1 + t}:\left[0,\rightarrow\right[ \to \left[0,1\right[
   $$
   Then $\varphi$ satisfies sub-additivity $\varphi(s + t) \leq \varphi(s) + \varphi(t)$, from which it follows that $\rho$ satisfies the various axioms of a metric.
2. A proof that $\rho$ and $d$ are topologically equivalent is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950208/let-rhox-y-fracdx-y1dx-y-show-that-rho-is-a-metric-equivalen). The trick is to observe that any open ball under $\rho$ is also an open ball under $d$ and vice versa.
3. $\rho$ is always a bounded metric bounded above by $1$, so any unbounded $d$ shows that the constant $C$ in $d < C\rho$ does not exist.
4. Metric equivalence, also called Lipschitz equivalence, is a stronger condition than topological equivalence.

Comment: thanks for editing point 3